# currency code is euro - the amount should be formatted with no decimal

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

- I am new to extjs

  - I am trying to to pass in a currency code and format the amount using
    the currency code..i.e. currency code is euro - the amount should be
    formatted with no decimal
  - providing my code below..

    ```
    columns : [
    {
        text      : 'Foo',
        dataIndex : 'foo',
        flex      : 1,
        renderer: function(val) {
            // '&#8364;' is the euro symbol
            return '&#8364;' + Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0.00')(val)
        }    
    }
    ```

    ]
  - it would be great if you guys provide some inputs...

Comment: Why have you tagged this angular? Am removing tag as question has nothing to do with tag

Answer (score 0):

for this use [Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-numberRenderer)

Here is a fiddle with an example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/l14

Greets